# How to verify the correctness of following equation as Gaussian formula?

Tags: numerical-methods, gaussian

How do I verify the correctness of this formula as Gaussian formula?
$$
\int^1_{-1}f(x)dx= f(-\alpha)+f(\alpha)
$$
$$\alpha=1/\sqrt{3}$$
I think I have to follow the theorem on Gaussian Quadrature, where we have
$$
\int^b_aq(x)p(x)w(x)dx=0
$$
But im not sure how to find q, p, w

Comment: "$\approx$" is mathematically not defined. We can only prove that the error is bounded by a specific expression.

Comment: Okay, it was written like that in my book. I have changed it now.

Comment: Peter, this is irrelevant for the question involved. You are not to prove it, but to verify the correctness. Therefore, it is defined and the approximation sign can be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that an integral can be given by
$$
\int_{\hat{x}}^{\bar{x}} f(x) dx  = A_0f(\hat{x}) + A_1f(\bar{x}).
$$

Hint:
Check correctness of the formula for f(x), where f(x) is a polynomial of degree 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.

Comment: Im not sure i understand this answer